# Apigee X OAuthv2 used as a cache

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-api, api-gateway, apigee

i'm trying to use OAuthv2 in APIGEE as a cache on Cassandra, the idea is to save an external token in memory, associated with an attribute and then retrieve the attribute in the next call based on the token we have associated with it.
It is the only way to use a "cache" at the cross environment level i think.
How can i do this in a simple way and is it possible to do it without using apigee apps?

Thank you in advice, regards.